# should i choose IAsyncEnumerable<T> or IEnumerable<Task<T>>?

Tags: c#

in my C# program, I have a list that has 100+ URLs and I will download files from those URLs.

at first, I will use `list.select(x=> DosomethingAsync(x))` then use `Task.WhenAny` to handle the result (these step is very fast, the main cost is file download)

```
while (!itemsTasks.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    Task<Stream> fininshed_item_task = await Task.WhenAny(itemsTasks);
    Stream itemResult = await fininshed_item_task;
            
    // do something with   itemResult
    ......
    itemsTasks.Remove(fininshed_item_task);
}
```

now I hear that there is IAsyncEnumerable and it seems could keep my code more straightforward.

but I am very worried IAsyncEnumerable will fetch file one by one and cost more time.
And I find that `IAsyncEnumerable` do a lot of thread changing!

`IEnumerable<Task<T>>` seems to start tasks immediately before await. and another problem is I need to find a way to cancel the remaining tasks if there is one get failed.

Can you explain this?

Comment: IMHO write an async method to process one item, then `Task.WhenAll`. Using `Task.WhenAny` isn't a great solution https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/

Answer (score 1):

Basically `IAsyncEnumerable` is an enumeration of awaited tasks' result while `IEnumerable<Task>` is an enumeration of tasks.

I would say that `IAsynEnumerable` is a shortcut feature for a specific usecase of `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`.

Let's say we have this expensive operation to perform

```cs
static async Task<int> ExpensiveOperationAsync(int number)
{
    // some expensive operation
    await Task.Delay(100);

    return number;
}
```

To return the operation's result on all of the positives numbers you obviously  could not just return a list of values since there is an infinite amount of them, so you would have to yield every result once the task has completed.

But this does not compile since `int` is not awaitable and the method is `async`.

```cs
static async int GetNumbersAsync()
{
    var i = 0;
    
    while (true)
    {
        yield return await ExpensiveOperationAsync(i++);
    }
}
```

One way around is to not use an `aync` method and just return the tasks, here we have our `IEnumerable<Task<int>>`.

```cs
static IEnumerable<Task<int>> GetNumbersAsyncEnumerableTasks()
{
    var i = 0;
    
    while (true)
    {
        yield return ExpensiveOperationAsync(i++);
    }
}
```

And use it

```cs
foreach (var task in GetNumbersAsyncEnumerableTasks())
    Console.WriteLine(await task);
```

But one downside of this approach is that it's not very explicit about what you are trying to achieve.

Instead C# provides a nicer way to do this, the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` which is a kind of an awaitable thing.

```cs
static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetNumbersAsyncEnumerable(int max)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
    {
        yield return await ExpensiveOperationAsync(i);
    }
}
```

```cs
// notice the await foreach syntax
await foreach (var number in GetNumbersAsyncEnumerable(10))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

As you can see `IAsynEnumerable<T>` is useful for a few specific situations but it does not seem to fit your case.

I rather do something like this

```cs
public class MyProcessor
{
    public async Task ProcessAllTasksAsync<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        var wrappedTasks = tasks.Select(TaskWrapperAsync);
        await Task.WhenAll(wrappedTasks);
    }

    private async Task TaskWrapperAsync<T>(Task<T> task)
    {
        var result = await task;
        DoSomethingWithItemResult(result);
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithItemResult<T>(T result)
    {
        // some cool stuff
    }
}
```